# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object (on my PlayerDeath Script)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Hey i'm new to literally everything, sorry if this was solved but i'm having trouble editing a script from Unity's Platformer 2D Game. There's an Error where Player can't die and the error NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. But idk the solution.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Platformer.Gameplay.PlayerDeath.Execute () (at Assets/Scripts/Gameplay/PlayerDeath.cs:20)
Platformer.Core.Simulation+Event`1[T].ExecuteEvent () (at Assets/Scripts/Core/Simulation.Event.cs:57)
Platformer.Core.Simulation.Tick () (at Assets/Scripts/Core/Simulation.cs:114)
Platformer.Mechanics.GameController.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Mechanics/GameController.cs:40)
```

This is my PlayerDeath

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Platformer.Core;
using Platformer.Model;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Platformer.Gameplay
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Fired when the player has died.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="PlayerDeath"></typeparam>
    public class PlayerDeath : Simulation.Event<PlayerDeath>
    {
        PlatformerModel model = Simulation.GetModel<PlatformerModel>();

        public override void Execute()
        {
            var player = model.player;
            if (player.health.IsAlive)
            {
                player.health.Die();
                model.virtualCamera.m_Follow = null;
                model.virtualCamera.m_LookAt = null;
                // player.collider.enabled = false;
                player.controlEnabled = false;

                if (player.audioSource && player.ouchAudio)
                    player.audioSource.PlayOneShot(player.ouchAudio);
                player.animator.SetTrigger("hurt");
                player.animator.SetBool("dead", true);
                Simulation.Schedule<PlayerSpawn>(2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Simulation.Event

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Platformer.Core
{
    public static partial class Simulation
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// An event is something that happens at a point in time in a simulation.
        /// The Precondition method is used to check if the event should be executed,
        /// as conditions may have changed in the simulation since the event was 
        /// originally scheduled.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="Event"></typeparam>
        public abstract class Event : System.IComparable<Event>
        {
            internal float tick;

            public int CompareTo(Event other)
            {
                return tick.CompareTo(other.tick);
            }

            public abstract void Execute();

            public virtual bool Precondition() => true;

            internal virtual void ExecuteEvent()
            {
                if (Precondition())
                    Execute();
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// This method is generally used to set references to null when required.
            /// It is automatically called by the Simulation when an event has completed.
            /// </summary>
            internal virtual void Cleanup()
            {

            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Event<T> adds the ability to hook into the OnExecute callback
        /// whenever the event is executed. Use this class to allow functionality
        /// to be plugged into your application with minimal or zero configuration.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        public abstract class Event<T> : Event where T : Event<T>
        {
            public static System.Action<T> OnExecute;

            internal override void ExecuteEvent()
            {
                if (Precondition())
                {
                    Execute();
                    OnExecute?.Invoke((T)this);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Simulation

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


namespace Platformer.Core
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The Simulation class implements the discrete event simulator pattern.
    /// Events are pooled, with a default capacity of 4 instances.
    /// </summary>
    public static partial class Simulation
    {

        static HeapQueue<Event> eventQueue = new HeapQueue<Event>();
        static Dictionary<System.Type, Stack<Event>> eventPools = new Dictionary<System.Type, Stack<Event>>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new event of type T and return it, but do not schedule it.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <returns></returns>
        static public T New<T>() where T : Event, new()
        {
            Stack<Event> pool;
            if (!eventPools.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out pool))
            {
                pool = new Stack<Event>(4);
                pool.Push(new T());
                eventPools[typeof(T)] = pool;
            }
            if (pool.Count > 0)
                return (T)pool.Pop();
            else
                return new T();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clear all pending events and reset the tick to 0.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Clear()
        {
            eventQueue.Clear();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Schedule an event for a future tick, and return it.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The event.</returns>
        /// <param name="tick">Tick.</param>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The event type parameter.</typeparam>
        static public T Schedule<T>(float tick = 0) where T : Event, new()
        {
            var ev = New<T>();
            ev.tick = Time.time + tick;
            eventQueue.Push(ev);
            return ev;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reschedule an existing event for a future tick, and return it.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The event.</returns>
        /// <param name="tick">Tick.</param>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The event type parameter.</typeparam>
        static public T Reschedule<T>(T ev, float tick) where T : Event, new()
        {
            ev.tick = Time.time + tick;
            eventQueue.Push(ev);
            return ev;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Return the simulation model instance for a class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        static public T GetModel<T>() where T : class, new()
        {
            return InstanceRegister<T>.instance;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set a simulation model instance for a class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        static public void SetModel<T>(T instance) where T : class, new()
        {
            InstanceRegister<T>.instance = instance;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Destroy the simulation model instance for a class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        static public void DestroyModel<T>() where T : class, new()
        {
            InstanceRegister<T>.instance = null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Tick the simulation. Returns the count of remaining events.
        /// If remaining events is zero, the simulation is finished unless events are
        /// injected from an external system via a Schedule() call.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        static public int Tick()
        {
            var time = Time.time;
            var executedEventCount = 0;
            while (eventQueue.Count > 0 && eventQueue.Peek().tick <= time)
            {
                var ev = eventQueue.Pop();
                var tick = ev.tick;
                ev.ExecuteEvent();
                if (ev.tick > tick)
                {
                    //event was rescheduled, so do not return it to the pool.
                }
                else
                {
                    // Debug.Log($"<color=green>{ev.tick} {ev.GetType().Name}</color>");
                    ev.Cleanup();
                    try
                    {
                        eventPools[ev.GetType()].Push(ev);
                    }
                    catch (KeyNotFoundException)
                    {
                        //This really should never happen inside a production build.
                        Debug.LogError($"No Pool for: {ev.GetType()}");
                    }
                }
                executedEventCount++;
            }
            return eventQueue.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my GameController

```
using Platformer.Core;
using Platformer.Model;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Platformer.Mechanics
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class exposes the the game model in the inspector, and ticks the
    /// simulation.
    /// </summary> 
    public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static GameController Instance { get; private set; }

        //This model field is public and can be therefore be modified in the 
        //inspector.
        //The reference actually comes from the InstanceRegister, and is shared
        //through the simulation and events. Unity will deserialize over this
        //shared reference when the scene loads, allowing the model to be
        //conveniently configured inside the inspector.
        public PlatformerModel model = Simulation.GetModel<PlatformerModel>();

        void Start()
        {
            Screen.SetResolution(1280, 720, true);
        }

        void OnEnable()
        {
            Instance = this;
        }

        void OnDisable()
        {
            if (Instance == this) Instance = null;
        }

        void Update()
        {
            if (Instance == this) Simulation.Tick();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same issue. The problem generally begins when we write a custom player instead of using the default.

What you need to do, at least for the 2D Platformer microgame, is open up the GameObject called "GameController" (should be right up at the top) and drag your player* onto the Player field under the GameController component.

*Specifically, the GameObject that has your PlayerController component.

(I really like that Unity is diving into a full event system like Qt, but this Simulation class seems very convoluted and graceless to me. We'll see what I think as I progress with it; but I doubt it's that much more efficient than cached GameObject.Find calls.)

That *should* solve your problem!

Comment: facing a similar error. But can't find the "GameController". can you be more specific?

Comment: If you don't have a GameController script, I'm not sure my answer applies to you... but, another possibility for that is not having filled out your inspector variables and one of them defaulting to null, then attempting to use them. Same message. Maybe that will help you?